# Importing data to drive animation

Tags: export, import

Blender noob would like to know if it is possible to import data from a file (say tab delimited text or csv format) to set values for animated objects in Blender.
Specifically, what I am trying to do is to animate a set of gauges driven by GPS data from a file. Some time ago, there were a couple of people working on importing GPS data into Blender but the files and the authors seem to have disappeared.
Scott :-)